# Apply a function to every arguments in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I sometimes find myself in a case where I need to create a function that maps a different function to two values, and then combines them together. How to do that without using a lambda ?

My functions are:

```
f :: a -> b
g :: c -> d
combine :: b -> d -> e
```

The question is: how to write `\x y -> combine (f x) (g y)` without using a lambda ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative pointfree spelling involves handling the arguments as a pair by using `curry`, `uncurry` and either `(***)` (from `Control.Arrow`) or `bimap` (from `Data.Bifunctor`):

```
GHCi> :t \combine f g -> curry (uncurry combine . (f *** g))
\combine f g -> curry (uncurry combine . (f *** g))
  :: (a1 -> b1 -> c) -> (a -> a1) -> (b -> b1) -> a -> b -> c
```

Note that, unlike jpath's suggestions, this isn't even shorter than the non-pointfree version.

Answer (score 7):

If `f = g` you can use `on` in `Data.Function`. Otherwise there is no combinator for that in `base`. A stackage search for the appropriate type reveals `biSp` from [`concatenative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/concatenative).

```
biSp :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> e
```

However if that is the only function you will be using from that package, you may not want to depend on a package just for that.

Other than that you can use the following which would be at least marginally shorter, but not really more readable.

```
(. g) . combine . f
```

Or using `dimap` in `Data.Profunctor` from [`profunctors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors). While this also requires another package, it is likely that you are already depending on `profunctors` indirectly anyway, because you are using `lens` or some package depending on `lens`.

```
dimap f (. g) combine
```

This can easily be extended to three arguments. The following all do the same and are ordered from shortest to most structured and with the last two it is especially easy to extend them to any number of arguments.

```
dimap f (dimap g (. h)) combine3
(dimap f . dimap g) (. h) combine3
(dimap f . dimap g . dimap h) id combine3
```

If you wonder what this `dimap` does. This is a great tutorial: [I love profunctors. They're so easy.](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/profunctors)

Or just write your own `biSp`.